# How to change query parameters serialization using nestjs/swagger?

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs, nestjs-swagger

Recently I have updated `nestjs/swagger` package in my project to `^4.0.0`. Previously Swagger serialized my query parameters as follows:

```
/resources?parameter=1,2,3
```

Now it looks like this:

```
/resources?parameter=1&parameter=2&parameter=3
```

DTO object for my query looks like this:

```
class QueryDTO {
  @ApiProperty({
    required: false,
    type: [Number],
  })
  @IsOptional()
  readonly parameter?: number[];
}
```

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 8):

I am on nestjs/swagger 4.5.9

I made it work by define the DTO ( notice the `format: 'form'`)

```
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiProperty({
    type: [Number],
    format: 'form',
  })
  @IsArray()
  @Transform((value: string) => value.split(',').map(item => Number(item)))
  @IsNumber({}, {each: true})
  deviceId: Array<number>;
```

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can remove the @ApiProperty from the DTO and use the @ApiQuery decorator on the controller method which has the style and explode options(just keep the same parameter name as the dto property)

```
    @Get('resources')
    @ApiQuery({
        name: 'parameter',
        required: false,
        explode: false,
        type: Number,
        isArray: true
    })
    getResources(@Query('parameter') parameter?: number[]) {}
```

You can still use the DTO object as it is for additional parameters that work the usual way.